# wordpress - no permission for plugin page

Tags: wordpress, cron

when i try to open the plugin file it gives me an error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page". how can access my page!

here is my code !

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin Display
Plugin URI: http://test.com
Description: Plugin for displaying info
Author: rohail
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://test.com
 */

add_action('wp', 'prefix_setup_schedule');
/**
 * On an early action hook, check if the hook is scheduled - if not, schedule it.
 */
function prefix_setup_schedule() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('prefix_hourly_event')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'prefix_hourly_event');
    }
}

add_action('prefix_hourly_event', 'prefix_do_this_hourly');
/**
 * On the scheduled action hook, run a function.
 */
function prefix_do_this_hourly() {
    echo "test test";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

usually due error(s) in the code

error can viewed by setting WP_DBUG to TRUE in wp-config file

WP_DEBUG is a PHP constant, used to trigger the “debug” mode throughout WordPress. It is assumed to be false by default and is usually set to true in the wp-config.php